# How to Register through facebook using Spring Social

Tags: java, spring, spring-social-facebook

I am new to Spring Social. I am working on java Spring Social application in which i want to be able to register through facebook. can anyone please respond with example to achieve it?

In Spring Controller callback method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/callback", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String postOnWall(@RequestParam("code") String code,
            @RequestParam("state") String state, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("hi welcome to callback method");

        OAuthService oAuthService = facebookServiceProvider.getService();

        Verifier verifier = new Verifier(code);
        Token accessToken = oAuthService
                .getAccessToken(Token.empty(), verifier);
//      Token accessToken = new Token("EAADOe1JXBWgBAJVtLpGKTM6pol0n8r8fZAHnEPmNZCnId9419k9EHj2scdtcZBotMW5oYneKTvY93ZASRpeUGLiXRKhWvuZBA3zfEgIjGpvLMZCzODvA3SuNm9glARg0c5puZARVuTyZAiSqibD76taIUk06O08lOSm2vJDufCAlUdIP8P9c4ZBLP", "", "");
        System.out.println("accessToken "+accessToken);

        FacebookTemplate template = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken.getToken());
        System.out.println(template.isAuthorized()+" autherized or not condition");
        FacebookProfile facebookProfile = template.userOperations()
                .getUserProfile();
        System.out.println("user permissions "+template.userOperations().getUserPermissions());

        String userId = facebookProfile.getId();

        System.out.println("user about "+facebookProfile.getAbout());

        LOGGER.info("Logged in User Id : {}", userId);

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = facebookUtil
                .publishLinkWithVisiblityRestriction(state);
        try {
            template.publish(facebookProfile.getId(), "feed", map);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "Exception Occurred while posting a link on facebook for user Id : {}, exception is : {}",
                    userId, ex);
            return PUBLISH_ERROR;
        }

        return PUBLISH_SUCCESS;
    }
```

In above method  i am getting all parameters (like email, first name, about etc) as null

Comment: where is your tried codes?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions below:

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/adding-social-sign-in-to-a-spring-mvc-web-application-registration-and-login/